create a linux shell alias from a python script
I want to write a python script, that sets some shell aliases, that can be executed after running the python script.
I have tried the following approaches:
import subprocess
command: str = 'alias mytest="echo test"'
subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)

import subprocess
command: str = 'alias mytest="echo test"'
subprocess.call(command, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')

import os
command: str = 'alias mytest="echo test"'
os.system(command)

import os
command: str = 'alias mytest="echo test"'
os.popen(command)

But after executing these scripts I was not able to call the alias.
I know, that I can set aliases via .bashrc, but I have written a environment in python to manage some dynamic attributes and run processes.
Now I want to make my life a little bit easier and set some aliases to call some functionality.

@Johnny Cheesecutter
os: linux
The aliases are only for the user.
I use a tool to process data and want to use python to start workflows in the tool and manage files. Shell-scripting is not an option, because of limited logging and other drawbacks. In python I read a bunch of config files, which are hierarchical yaml files. There are static values, dynamic status values and combined values.
A simple example:
Path to the source files for a specific DAY_NUMBER: /mydata/system1/filetype1/<DAY_NUMBER>/
The aliases are needed to make my life a little bit easier. If I want to go to the current source-file-directory I only want to type srccurr instead of cd /mydata/system1/filetype1/<DAY_NUMBER>/ So I have to define a aliases. But depending of the current load-status the DAY_NUMBER could be different. The value of the DAY_NUMBER ist stored in one of the yaml-files.

That only sets the alias in the shell started by subprocess.run, which exits immediately after the alias command is complete. You cannot modify your current shell using a Python script.

Usually what you do is have your Python script output a shell command to be executed by eval, so you would put something like eval $(python my_env.py) in your .bashrc  or .bash_profile file. This requires you to be certain that it will be safe to evaluate whatever my_env.py actually outputs.

Or you could make a fn/alias like mySetup="python my_env.py > /.myenv.py ; source myenv.py" . Good luck.

Hi, what do you mean by written a environment in python to manage some dynamic attributes and run processes.? Could you please share more details. Adding aliases could be different depending on how you've created environments. Also are you on linux or mac? Do you want to add aliases in the environment or just for the user?

This is crazy on so many levels. The obvious solution is alias something=$(external command which prints the definition) where the external command can be Python or whatever you fancy.

Thank you @chepner - that works
set_alias.py
aliases: str = '''alias mytest1="echo test_1";
alias mytest2="echo test_2";
alias mytest3="echo test_3"'''
print(aliases)

shell:
eval "$(python set_alias.py)"

mytest1


eval "$(python set_alias.py)", not eval $(python set_alias.py). The difference doesn't matter for the specific aliases you're setting here, but if (for example) the Python were emitting alias mytest3="echo ' * HELLO * '", leaving out the syntactic quotes on the eval command would cause the *s to be replaced with lists of filenames in the current directory where that eval command was run.

If you change your python script to something like this:
script.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print('alias mytest="echo test"')

And, launch it like this in bash:
source <(./script.py)

Then, all the commands spit out by the script will be executed in the current shell.

Here is my final solution:
aliases.py
import sys
import my_config_class

def get_alias_command(alias: str):
    alias_command: str = None
    my_config = my_config_class.Config()
    match alias:
        case "alias1":
            alias_command = f"cd {my_config.dir_1}"
        case "alias2":
            alias_command = f"cd {my_config.dir_2}"
    print(alias_command)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    alias = sys.argv[1]
    get_alias_command(alias)

alias.sh
alias alias1='eval "$(python aliases.py alias1)"'
alias alias2='eval "$(python aliases.py alias2)"'

First source the alias.sh
source alias.sh
Then use the alias
alias1
This version always uses the current values from the python class, because the eval will only be executed, when the alias is called.

Arguably you don't need the eval at all here -- alias alias1="$(python aliases.py alias1)" will work perfectly well when your Python is emitting correctly-escaped data. (It's not, but your current code would require the Python to escape values twice to be correct with all possible directory names; with the change suggested above, you only need to escape it once; f"cd {shlex.quote(my_config.dir_1)}" for example will do that, after of course adding import shlex to the top of the script).
